# subscheme where two morphisms agree is points where they agree on residue fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X, Y, Z$ be schemes, where $X, Y$ are $Z$ schemes.  I know the definition of "the locally closed subscheme of $X$ where two $Z$-  morphisms $\pi, \pi': X\rightarrow Y$ agree" from its universal property.  Also I can define it as the fiber product of the diagonal $$\delta :  Y\rightarrow Y\times_Z Y$$ with $$(\pi, \pi'): X\rightarrow Y\times_Z Y.$$

My question:  **how to prove that the underlying set of "the locally closed subscheme where the two morphisms agree" is the same as the set of points where the two morphism agree on the residue field.**

It is probably clear thatthe former is contained in the latter, but why is it all of them?  That is, why is a point where $\pi, \pi'$ agree on the residue field necessarily contained in "the subscheme where $\pi, \pi'$ agree"?

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "agree"?

Comment: @KReiser in which instance? u mean w.r.t. the residue field?

Comment: Both - I'm trying to get you to define your terms.

Comment: @KReiser so with "the locally closed subscheme where the two morphisms agree" i know the definition using the universal property: $\pi \circ \iota = \pi' \circ \iota$ and any other such $\iota'$ factors uniquely through $\iota$ . and i also know the definition as the fiber product i describe above.  W.r.t residue fields, $\pi$ and $\pi'$ induce field homs $\mathcal{O}_{Y, \pi(p)=\pi'(p)}/\mathfrak{m}_{\pi(p)} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X, p}/\mathfrak{m_p}$ so we require those to be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let "the set where the morphisms agree" be called $A$ and the fiber product $X\times_{Y\times_Z Y} Y$ be called $V$. Our goal is to show the underlying sets are equal. You state in your post that you are ok with $V\subset A$ set-theoretically (where we fudge things a little and identify $V$ with it's image under the immersion $V\to X$).

To show that $V=A$ set theoretically, it is enough to show that if $a\in A$, the fiber $V \times_X \operatorname{Spec} k(a)$ is nonempty. To start, we define the maps $i:\operatorname{Spec} k(a)\to X$ given by the standard inclusion and $j:\operatorname{Spec} k(a)\to Y$ given by $j((0))=f(a)$ as sets and $j^\sharp:\mathcal{O}_Y \to j_*\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} k(a)}$ is given by $\mathcal{O}_Y(U)\to \mathcal{O}_{Y,f(a)} \to k(f(a)) \to k(a)$ if $a\in U$ and $0$ otherwise. As $i$ and $j$ agree when composed with the maps to $Y\times_ZY$, this gives a map $\operatorname{Spec} k(a)\to V$ so that the composite of this map with the natural projections $V\to X$ and $V\to Y$ agree with $i$ and $j$ by the universal property of the fiber product. But this means that there's a point of $V$ which maps to $a$ and we're done.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have just finished this section in Vakil myself, so I am happy to be corrected by more experienced AGers.

Claim (see the discussion above Vakil 10.2 B): The set of points where two morphisms of $Z$-schemes $\pi, \pi' : X \to Y$ agree is the set of point on which those morphisms agree (on the level of points) and on induced maps of residue fields.

Let $\pi^{\#}_x$ and $\pi'^{\#}_x$ denote the maps of residue fields at $x \in X$ induced by $\pi$ and $\pi'$, respectively. By the universal property of the locus where two schemes agree, we must show

$$X \times_{Y \times_Z Y} Y$$

is in bijective correspondence as a set to

$$\{x \in X \ | \ \pi(x) = \pi'(x), \pi^{\#}_x  =\pi'^{\#}_x \}$$

Recall that points of $$X \times_{Y \times_Z Y} Y$$ are in bijective correspondence with tuples $(x, y, z, P)$ such that $\delta(y) = (y, y) = (\pi, \pi')(x) = z$ and $P \subset \kappa(x) \otimes_{\kappa(z)} \kappa(y)$ is prime. See Stacks Project, Lemma 26.17.5.

Clearly it is necessary that $\pi(x) = \pi'(x)$ for these conditions to be satisfied.

Now, again by Lemma 26.17.5, primes $P \subset \kappa(x) \otimes_{\kappa(z)} \kappa(y)$ have $\kappa(P)$ corresponding to $\kappa(z) = \kappa(\pi(x), \pi(x)) = \kappa(\pi'(x), \pi'(x))$ in the lower right corner of the tensor product diagram.

But $\kappa(P)$ then corresponds to the diagonal map $\kappa(y) = \kappa(\pi(x)) = \kappa(\pi'(x)) \to \kappa(x)$ found in the tensor product diagram. Hence, given such a prime, since $z$ is both $(\pi(x), \pi(x))$ and $(\pi'(x), \pi'(x))$, this diagonal map is both the map $\pi^{\#}_x$ and $\pi'^{\#}_x$, and so they are the same map.

Comment: Oops, you are correct about that, my apologies. Though the example of $X=\operatorname{Spec} k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$ and the two maps induced by $id$ and $\epsilon\mapsto 0$ does show that $X$ is not the same as $X\times_{Y\times_Z Y} Y$ as schemes. I do think something's funny about the fact that you didn't use anything about the induced maps on residue fields, and I suspect that this should probably be used in the choice of $P$ (this looks a little funny to me - your proof appears to work on Vakil's example with $\Bbb C$, for instance), though I don't have a full fix right now.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Apologies, i'm clearly missing something-- could you say a little bit about how your claim implies what i'm trying to prove

Comment: nm i was being stupid, sorry. i will get some sleep and take it up in the morning.  thank you again!

Comment: Dear Johnny Apple, unfortunately I'm a little busy right now and I don't have as much time as I need to unwind all the stuff that's going on with the tensor products in this answer (I'm not sure if there's an error in my understanding or your answer, but something feels funny to me and I can't pin it down). I'll do my best to figure it out when I get a chance and hopefully I'll post something helpful at some point.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative  to the excellent accepted answer: If $\pi, \pi'$ agree at $ p$ let $ \varphi: Spec(\kappa(p))\rightarrow X.$ Then $ \pi \circ \varphi=\pi'\circ \varphi$ thus $ \varphi$ factors through the scheme where $\pi, \pi'$ agree. Thus $ p$ is in the latter.